# PHP: read in database keys from file

Tags: php, database, git, file, authentication

We have a php file that initializes a database connection using a private key.  We want to keep these private keys off of our git repo, and are attempting to find a solution that would allow for this.  Keeping the private key in a separate file would accomplish what we want, we would simply not commit that file to the repo.

What is the best way to go about doing this, should the key just be stored in a .txt file with restricted permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common solution to this problem is to have a config file, say `config.php`, that contains sensitive information, and to exclude the config file from repository via the `.gitignore` file. The config file can be a simple PHP file that sets some global variables which can be referenced in the other files.

If it ends up containing several variables and you are working with other people, you might want to also create a `config.php.sample` file which *is* added to the repository and has typical values but leaves password and private key variables blank. Collaborators are then instructed to copy that file to `config.php` and enter the information for their system.